# Offset Background Image

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-position

How do I offset background image in such a way that the background only reveals the bottom half of the image from the top of the parent container while the other top half of the image is hidden as if the "overflow: hidden" command was applied to it.

i understand it can be done with background position, but how?

```css
.container{
    background-image: url(./images/bg-pattern-circles.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    padding: 10rem 2.5rem 8rem;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0 7rem 0 7rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.container::before{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(hsl(237, 17%, 21%), hsl(237, 23%, 32%));
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>State of the Art Infrastructure</h3>
  <p>With reliability and speed in mind, worldwide data centers provide the backbone for ultra-fast connectivity. This ensures your site will load instantly, no matter where your readers are, keeping your site competitive.</p>
</div>
```

This is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHxhR.jpg) of what I'm trying to achieve (the circle in the background). This is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AphEq.png) of the circle in the background.

Comment: Background position won't help you with the white curves though. I would do it by either editing the image in an image editor before using it as a background, or by [stacking another background image](https://css-tricks.com/css-basics-using-multiple-backgrounds/) (white and transparent) on top as a mask.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand it can be done with background position, but how?

One way to do it is like this:

```css
background-position: center -509px;
```

Since your background image is `1018px` tall, you simply pull it up by half that amount.

Here's a demo:

```css
.container{
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AphEq.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center -509px;
    padding: 10rem 2.5rem 8rem;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0 7rem 0 7rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.container::before{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(hsl(237, 17%, 21%), hsl(237, 23%, 32%));
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>State of the Art Infrastructure</h3>
  <p>With reliability and speed in mind, worldwide data centers provide the backbone for ultra-fast connectivity. This ensures your site will load instantly, no matter where your readers are, keeping your site competitive.</p>
</div>
```